# AcceleratorKeyActivated event args KeyStatus.WasKeyDown field is always false when key is down

Tags: uwp, windows-10, keyboard-events, c++-cx

When a key is pressed and held CoreDispatcher::AcceleratorKeyActivated event is fired and KeyStatus.WasKeyDown field is always false. CoreWindow::KeyDown event has WasKeyDown set correctly. Actually it seems like behavior was changed recently. Previously holding a key was causing KeyDown / KeyUp events, but now it only causes KeyDown. Can somebody confirm this?

Here is some example:

```cpp
//  IFrameworkView::SetWindow implementation
public: virtual void
SetWindow(::Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow ^ h_window)
{
    h_window->Dispatcher->AcceleratorKeyActivated += ref new ::Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler
    <
        ::Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcher ^
    ,   ::Windows::UI::Core::AcceleratorKeyEventArgs ^
    >
    (this, &CView::On_Key);
    h_window->KeyDown += ref new ::Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler
    <
        ::Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow ^
    ,   ::Windows::UI::Core::KeyEventArgs ^
    >
    (this, &CView::On_KeyDown);
    h_window->KeyUp += ref new ::Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler
    <
        ::Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow ^
    ,   ::Windows::UI::Core::KeyEventArgs ^
    >
    (this, &CView::On_KeyUp);
}

private: static void
Trace_InputEvent
(
    wchar_t const *                     psz_description
,   ::Windows::System::VirtualKey const virtual_key
,   bool const                          was_down
,   bool const                          is_released
,   unsigned int const                  repeats_count
)
{
    ::std::wstringstream ss;
    ss << psz_description;
    ss << L" " << static_cast< int >(virtual_key);
    if(was_down)
    {
        ss << L" was down";
    }
    if(is_released)
    {
        ss << L" is released";
    }
    if(1 < repeats_count)
    {
        ss << L" repeats for " << repeats_count;
    }
    ss << L"\n";
    ss.flush();
    ::OutputDebugStringW(ss.str().c_str());
}

private: void
On_Key
(
    ::Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcher ^          h_dispatcher
,   ::Windows::UI::Core::AcceleratorKeyEventArgs ^ h_args
)
{
    auto const key_down
    {
        (::Windows::UI::Core::CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType::SystemKeyDown == h_args->EventType)
        ||
        (::Windows::UI::Core::CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType::KeyDown       == h_args->EventType)
    };
    auto const key_up
    {
        (::Windows::UI::Core::CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType::SystemKeyUp == h_args->EventType)
        ||
        (::Windows::UI::Core::CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType::KeyUp       == h_args->EventType)
    };
    if(key_down || key_up)
    {
        Trace_InputEvent
        (
            (key_down ? L"On_Key(Down)" : L"On_Key(Up)")
        ,   h_args->VirtualKey
        ,   h_args->KeyStatus.WasKeyDown
        ,   h_args->KeyStatus.IsKeyReleased
        ,   h_args->KeyStatus.RepeatCount
        );
    }
    //h_args->Handled = true; // Marking event as handled prevents On_KeyDown / On_KeyUp events from being emmitted.
}

private: void
On_KeyDown
(
    ::Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow ^   h_dispatcher
,   ::Windows::UI::Core::KeyEventArgs ^ h_args
)
{
    Trace_InputEvent
    (
        L"On_KeyDown"
    ,   h_args->VirtualKey
    ,   h_args->KeyStatus.WasKeyDown
    ,   h_args->KeyStatus.IsKeyReleased
    ,   h_args->KeyStatus.RepeatCount
    );
}

private: void
On_KeyUp
(
    ::Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow ^   h_dispatcher
,   ::Windows::UI::Core::KeyEventArgs ^ h_args
)
{
    Trace_InputEvent
    (
        L"On_KeyUp"
    ,   h_args->VirtualKey
    ,   h_args->KeyStatus.WasKeyDown
    ,   h_args->KeyStatus.IsKeyReleased
    ,   h_args->KeyStatus.RepeatCount
    );
}
```

Pressing and holding Spacebar outputs:

```
On_Key(Down) 32
On_KeyDown 32
On_Key(Down) 32
On_KeyDown 32 was down
On_Key(Down) 32
On_KeyDown 32 was down
...
On_Key(Down) 32
On_KeyDown 32 was down
On_Key(Up) 32 was down is released
On_KeyUp 32 was down is released
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue in RS1. It is also reported in MSDN forum: [CoreDispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated event: WasKeyDown property behaves differently on 10586.753 and 14393.693 (anniversary edition)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/945a3dae-6f22-432a-877f-52af7475ce68/uwpcoredispatcheracceleratorkeyactivated-event-waskeydown-property-behaves-differently-on?forum=wpdevelop)

During the process XAML is using, `KeyStatus` inside **AcceleratorKeyEventArgs** was ignored, so `WasKeyDown` is incorrect.

As a workaround, please use [`GetKeyState(VirtualKey)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow#Windows_UI_Core_CoreWindow_GetKeyState_Windows_System_VirtualKey_) method instead.

```
private void Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
{
            var corewindow = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AcceleratorKeyActivated-VirtualKey: " + 
            args.VirtualKey
            + " -- KeyState: " + 
            corewindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Space));//Here
}
```

Output:

```
AcceleratorKeyActivated-VirtualKey: Space -- KeyState: Down, Locked
AcceleratorKeyActivated-VirtualKey: Space -- KeyState: Down, Locked
AcceleratorKeyActivated-VirtualKey: Space -- KeyState: Down, Locked
AcceleratorKeyActivated-VirtualKey: Space -- KeyState: Down, Locked
AcceleratorKeyActivated-VirtualKey: Space -- KeyState: Down, Locked
AcceleratorKeyActivated-VirtualKey: Space -- KeyState: Locked
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, however your workaround is not correct. Checking that key is down now is not the same as checking that it was down. It will not allow you to distinguish between the first key down event (where was_down is false) and consecutive key down events sent while key is still pressed. I guess i need to manually track pressed state of all the keys of interest to be able to check "was_down" properly.

Comment: Also i must mention that something is wrong with MSDN forums search. For example [searching for AcceleratorKeyEventArgs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/home?searchTerm=AcceleratorKeyActivated+) randomly yields either 3 results or no results.

Comment: @dodo951 I see, if you have any issues when using MSDN forum, please report it in here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/home?forum=reportabug